# tree View fullpath stripping

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

Here is the application on codeplex all i did is created a new text box and trying to get path of current node selected into this text box, but i am getting extra things which i dont need at all,

Link to application,

[Codeplex app](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/my_explorer.aspx)

Code Line i am using is ,

```
TextBox1.Text = nodeCurrent.FullPath;
```

and output i am getting is something like this,

> My Computer\C:\\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop

My Computer here is Root Node, which i dont need, all i want is

> C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop

Picture added

[image]

Here is the function i am using it

```
private void tvFolders_AfterSelect(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        //Populate folders and files when a folder is selected
        this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

        //get current selected drive or folder
        TreeNode nodeCurrent = e.Node;
        string newPath = getFullPath(nodeCurrent.FullPath);
        tbDirectory.Text = newPath;


        //clear all sub-folders
        nodeCurrent.Nodes.Clear();

        if (nodeCurrent.SelectedImageIndex == 0)
        {
            //Selected My Computer - repopulate drive list
            PopulateDriveList();
        }
        else
        {
            //populate sub-folders and folder files
            PopulateDirectory(nodeCurrent, nodeCurrent.Nodes);
        }
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
```

Comment: Check `Jim Mischel's` answer as there's a method in the article that does the same thing as I suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the following line in the code and it will remove recurring "\" in the path

```
newPath = newPath.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like the `getFullPath` method in that code will do exactly what you want. It strips the `MyComputer\` string and returns the rest. Write:

```
string newPath = getFullPath(nodeCurrent.FullPath);
```

Comment: half of my problem is solved, now how to get rid of "\" that comes after "C:\\" as i just need one & i doubt if i can remove it as when i just click on drive c node it gives me "C:/" but when i go to sub folder like documents it gives me C://Documents

Comment: @TimeToThine: I don't see anything in the code that would make it put in a double backslash. Are you seeing those "\\" displayed in the interface?

Comment: I added the picture sir, how it looks like

Comment: @TimeToThine: You'll have to single-step in the debugger to see where it's getting that extra `\\` character. A cursory look at the source doesn't reveal anything to me.

Comment: @ Trying to debug, just noticed one thing, its getting drive name as "C:/" and then when it adds paths to it, need to remove it now, brb

Comment: thats how it takes drive name as "nodeTreeNode = new TreeNode(mo["Name"].ToString() + "\\" ,imageIndex,selectIndex);"  but if i remove the \\ it will not allow me to get into drive anymore , STUCK :/